# How to Install PyMuPDF on Heroku Django

Tags: python, django, pdf, heroku, pymupdf

I am trying to make a script that extracts Images from PDF and I have made a script in a Django Project and added pymupdf to the requirements.txt.I Have an Aptfile with Mupdf in it and https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt as a buildpack along with heroku/python.While trying to push master to Heroku,The Push fails and here is the Error.

```
    Enumerating objects: 5, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 322 bytes | 322.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Apt app detected
remote: -----> Detected Aptfile or Stack changes, flushing cache
remote: -----> Adding custom repositories
remote: -----> Updating apt caches
remote:        Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease [242 kB]
remote:        Get:2 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt bionic-pgdg InRelease [46.3 kB]
remote:        Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]
remote:        Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]
remote:        Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages [11.3 MB]
remote:        Get:6 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt bionic-pgdg/11 amd64 Packages [2,483 B]
remote:        Get:7 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt bionic-pgdg/main amd64 Packages [294 kB]
remote:        Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages [1,344 kB]
remote:        Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 Packages [817 kB]
remote:        Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages [812 kB]
remote:        Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages [1,101 kB]
remote:        Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages [1,343 kB]
remote:        Fetched 17.5 MB in 3s (5,813 kB/s)
remote:        Reading package lists...
remote: -----> Fetching .debs for mupdf
remote:        Reading package lists...
remote:        Building dependency tree...
remote:        The following additional packages will be installed:
remote:          libopenjp2-7
remote:        Suggested packages:
remote:          mupdf-tools
remote:        The following NEW packages will be installed:
remote:          libopenjp2-7 mupdf
remote:        0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 46 not upgraded.
remote:        Need to get 19.2 MB of archives.
remote:        After this operation, 35.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
remote:        Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 libopenjp2-7 amd64 2.3.0-2build0.18.04.1 [145 kB]
remote:        Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 mupdf amd64 1.12.0+ds1-1 [19.0 MB]
remote:        Fetched 19.2 MB in 1s (13.5 MB/s)
remote:        Download complete and in download only mode
remote: -----> Installing libopenjp2-7_2.3.0-2build0.18.04.1_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing mupdf_1.12.0+ds1-1_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Writing profile script
remote: -----> Rewrite package-config files
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Need to update SQLite3, clearing cache
remote: -----> Installing python-3.6.10
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: Sqlite3 successfully installed.
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting bs4==0.0.1 (from -r /tmp/build_460e46d9ff4616a54e3ebd7caa495280/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/10/ed/7e8b97591f6f456174139ec089c769f89a94a1a4025fe967691de971f314/bs4-0.0.1.tar.gz
remote:        Collecting Django==2.1.11 (from -r /tmp/build_460e46d9ff4616a54e3ebd7caa495280/requirements.txt (line 2))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8c/49/d5038239995594281478bf209f8d93524ad342d500009a697b27f884668a/Django-2.1.11-py3-none-any.whl (7.3MB)
remote:        Collecting django-heroku==0.3.1 (from -r /tmp/build_460e46d9ff4616a54e3ebd7caa495280/requirements.txt (line 3))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/59/af/5475a876c5addd5a3494db47d9f7be93cc14d3a7603542b194572791b6c6/django_heroku-0.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting django-widget-tweaks==1.4.5 (from -r /tmp/build_460e46d9ff4616a54e3ebd7caa495280/requirements.txt (line 4))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1c/11/a8d3a4d73a09973d62ce381fb73a926707cb1485aa29599f2afc04dee7b4/django_widget_tweaks-1.4.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting forex-python==1.5 (from -r /tmp/build_460e46d9ff4616a54e3ebd7caa495280/requirements.txt (line 5))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1a/ff/f3f6da21e8fdc6ece355643871749c79a3191fed1cba088cbd0dc597dfee/forex-python-1.5.tar.gz
remote:        Collecting gunicorn==19.9.0 (from -r /tmp/build_460e46d9ff4616a54e3ebd7caa495280/requirements.txt (line 6))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8c/da/b8dd8deb741bff556db53902d4706774c8e1e67265f69528c14c003644e6/gunicorn-19.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (112kB)
remote:        Collecting imageio==2.6.1 (from -r /tmp/build_460e46d9ff4616a54e3ebd7caa495280/requirements.txt (line 7))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1a/de/f7f985018f462ceeffada7f6e609919fbcc934acd9301929cba14bc2c24a/imageio-2.6.1-py3-none-any.whl (3.3MB)
remote:        Collecting img2pdf==0.3.3 (from -r /tmp/build_460e46d9ff4616a54e3ebd7caa495280/requirements.txt (line 8))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e0/c6/7cd14232a1b10bf884c12daf3626afb76c4f60b52ae0eb23ce1519542ae4/img2pdf-0.3.3.tar.gz (80kB)
remote:        Collecting imutils==0.5.3 (from -r /tmp/build_460e46d9ff4616a54e3ebd7caa495280/requirements.txt (line 9))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b5/94/46dcae8c061e28be31bcaa55c560cb30ee9403c9a4bb2659768ec1b9eb7d/imutils-0.5.3.tar.gz
remote:        Collecting opencv-python-headless==4.1.2.30 (from -r /tmp/build_460e46d9ff4616a54e3ebd7caa495280/requirements.txt (line 10))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5d/96/b2824df85d8c5f148125e4fee073a62fde17639502fe67042b212ebfe488/opencv_python_headless-4.1.2.30-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (21.8MB)
remote:        Collecting pandas==0.25.3 (from -r /tmp/build_460e46d9ff4616a54e3ebd7caa495280/requirements.txt (line 11))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/52/3f/f6a428599e0d4497e1595030965b5ba455fd8ade6e977e3c819973c4b41d/pandas-0.25.3-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (10.4MB)
remote:        Collecting Pillow==6.1.0 (from -r /tmp/build_460e46d9ff4616a54e3ebd7caa495280/requirements.txt (line 12))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/14/41/db6dec65ddbc176a59b89485e8cc136a433ed9c6397b6bfe2cd38412051e/Pillow-6.1.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.1MB)
remote:        Collecting Pygments==2.4.2 (from -r /tmp/build_460e46d9ff4616a54e3ebd7caa495280/requirements.txt (line 13))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5c/73/1dfa428150e3ccb0fa3e68db406e5be48698f2a979ccbcec795f28f44048/Pygments-2.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (883kB)
remote:        Collecting pypandoc==1.4 (from -r /tmp/build_460e46d9ff4616a54e3ebd7caa495280/requirements.txt (line 14))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/71/81/00184643e5a10a456b4118fc12c96780823adb8ed974eb2289f29703b29b/pypandoc-1.4.tar.gz
remote:        Collecting PyPDF2==1.26.0 (from -r /tmp/build_460e46d9ff4616a54e3ebd7caa495280/requirements.txt (line 15))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b4/01/68fcc0d43daf4c6bdbc6b33cc3f77bda531c86b174cac56ef0ffdb96faab/PyPDF2-1.26.0.tar.gz (77kB)
remote:        Collecting scikit-image==0.16.2 (from -r /tmp/build_460e46d9ff4616a54e3ebd7caa495280/requirements.txt (line 16))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c8/bb/771800366f41d66eef51e4b80515f8ef7edab234a3f244fdce3bafe89b39/scikit_image-0.16.2-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (26.5MB)
remote:        Collecting whitenoise==5.0.1 (from -r /tmp/build_460e46d9ff4616a54e3ebd7caa495280/requirements.txt (line 17))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ae/25/0c8f08c9d3c93192cd286594f1e87b17bab496fb9082c2a69e17051b91fd/whitenoise-5.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting xlrd==1.2.0 (from -r /tmp/build_460e46d9ff4616a54e3ebd7caa495280/requirements.txt (line 18))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b0/16/63576a1a001752e34bf8ea62e367997530dc553b689356b9879339cf45a4/xlrd-1.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (103kB)
remote:        Collecting zipp==0.6.0 (from -r /tmp/build_460e46d9ff4616a54e3ebd7caa495280/requirements.txt (line 19))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/74/3d/1ee25a26411ba0401b43c6376d2316a71addcc72ef8690b101b4ea56d76a/zipp-0.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting python-docx (from -r /tmp/build_460e46d9ff4616a54e3ebd7caa495280/requirements.txt (line 20))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e4/83/c66a1934ed5ed8ab1dbb9931f1779079f8bca0f6bbc5793c06c4b5e7d671/python-docx-0.8.10.tar.gz (5.5MB)
remote:        Collecting pymupdf (from -r /tmp/build_460e46d9ff4616a54e3ebd7caa495280/requirements.txt (line 21))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3d/6a/5b4d4f1964a0802f8f2514fcd1f8d53c7f1e74a55765f99df1cf482bbbe8/PyMuPDF-1.16.10.tar.gz (175kB)
remote:        Collecting beautifulsoup4 (from bs4==0.0.1->-r /tmp/build_460e46d9ff4616a54e3ebd7caa495280/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cb/a1/c698cf319e9cfed6b17376281bd0efc6bfc8465698f54170ef60a485ab5d/beautifulsoup4-4.8.2-py3-none-any.whl (106kB)
remote:        Collecting pytz (from Django==2.1.11->-r /tmp/build_460e46d9ff4616a54e3ebd7caa495280/requirements.txt (line 2))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e7/f9/f0b53f88060247251bf481fa6ea62cd0d25bf1b11a87888e53ce5b7c8ad2/pytz-2019.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (509kB)
remote:        Collecting dj-database-url>=0.5.0 (from django-heroku==0.3.1->-r /tmp/build_460e46d9ff4616a54e3ebd7caa495280/requirements.txt (line 3))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d4/a6/4b8578c1848690d0c307c7c0596af2077536c9ef2a04d42b00fabaa7e49d/dj_database_url-0.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting psycopg2 (from django-heroku==0.3.1->-r /tmp/build_460e46d9ff4616a54e3ebd7caa495280/requirements.txt (line 3))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/84/d7/6a93c99b5ba4d4d22daa3928b983cec66df4536ca50b22ce5dcac65e4e71/psycopg2-2.8.4.tar.gz (377kB)
remote:        Collecting requests (from forex-python==1.5->-r /tmp/build_460e46d9ff4616a54e3ebd7caa495280/requirements.txt (line 5))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/51/bd/23c926cd341ea6b7dd0b2a00aba99ae0f828be89d72b2190f27c11d4b7fb/requests-2.22.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (57kB)
remote:        Collecting simplejson (from forex-python==1.5->-r /tmp/build_460e46d9ff4616a54e3ebd7caa495280/requirements.txt (line 5))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/98/87/a7b98aa9256c8843f92878966dc3d8d914c14aad97e2c5ce4798d5743e07/simplejson-3.17.0.tar.gz (83kB)
remote:        Collecting numpy (from imageio==2.6.1->-r /tmp/build_460e46d9ff4616a54e3ebd7caa495280/requirements.txt (line 7))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/62/20/4d43e141b5bc426ba38274933ef8e76e85c7adea2c321ecf9ebf7421cedf/numpy-1.18.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (20.1MB)
remote:        Collecting python-dateutil>=2.6.1 (from pandas==0.25.3->-r /tmp/build_460e46d9ff4616a54e3ebd7caa495280/requirements.txt (line 11))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d4/70/d60450c3dd48ef87586924207ae8907090de0b306af2bce5d134d78615cb/python_dateutil-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (227kB)
remote:        Collecting matplotlib!=3.0.0,>=2.0.0 (from scikit-image==0.16.2->-r /tmp/build_460e46d9ff4616a54e3ebd7caa495280/requirements.txt (line 16))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7e/07/4b361d6d0f4e08942575f83a11d33f36897e1aae4279046606dd1808778a/matplotlib-3.1.3-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (13.1MB)
remote:        Collecting networkx>=2.0 (from scikit-image==0.16.2->-r /tmp/build_460e46d9ff4616a54e3ebd7caa495280/requirements.txt (line 16))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/41/8f/dd6a8e85946def36e4f2c69c84219af0fa5e832b018c970e92f2ad337e45/networkx-2.4-py3-none-any.whl (1.6MB)
remote:        Collecting PyWavelets>=0.4.0 (from scikit-image==0.16.2->-r /tmp/build_460e46d9ff4616a54e3ebd7caa495280/requirements.txt (line 16))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/59/bb/d2b85265ec9fa3c1922210c9393d4cdf7075cc87cce6fe671d7455f80fbc/PyWavelets-1.1.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (4.4MB)
remote:        Collecting scipy>=0.19.0 (from scikit-image==0.16.2->-r /tmp/build_460e46d9ff4616a54e3ebd7caa495280/requirements.txt (line 16))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/dc/29/162476fd44203116e7980cfbd9352eef9db37c49445d1fec35509022f6aa/scipy-1.4.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (26.1MB)
remote:        Collecting more-itertools (from zipp==0.6.0->-r /tmp/build_460e46d9ff4616a54e3ebd7caa495280/requirements.txt (line 19))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/72/96/4297306cc270eef1e3461da034a3bebe7c84eff052326b130824e98fc3fb/more_itertools-8.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (43kB)
remote:        Collecting lxml>=2.3.2 (from python-docx->-r /tmp/build_460e46d9ff4616a54e3ebd7caa495280/requirements.txt (line 20))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/dd/ba/a0e6866057fc0bbd17192925c1d63a3b85cf522965de9bc02364d08e5b84/lxml-4.5.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (5.8MB)
remote:        Collecting soupsieve>=1.2 (from beautifulsoup4->bs4==0.0.1->-r /tmp/build_460e46d9ff4616a54e3ebd7caa495280/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/81/94/03c0f04471fc245d08d0a99f7946ac228ca98da4fa75796c507f61e688c2/soupsieve-1.9.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests->forex-python==1.5->-r /tmp/build_460e46d9ff4616a54e3ebd7caa495280/requirements.txt (line 5))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b9/63/df50cac98ea0d5b006c55a399c3bf1db9da7b5a24de7890bc9cfd5dd9e99/certifi-2019.11.28-py2.py3-none-any.whl (156kB)
remote:        Collecting chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 (from requests->forex-python==1.5->-r /tmp/build_460e46d9ff4616a54e3ebd7caa495280/requirements.txt (line 5))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/a9/01ffebfb562e4274b6487b4bb1ddec7ca55ec7510b22e4c51f14098443b8/chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133kB)
remote:        Collecting idna<2.9,>=2.5 (from requests->forex-python==1.5->-r /tmp/build_460e46d9ff4616a54e3ebd7caa495280/requirements.txt (line 5))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/14/2c/cd551d81dbe15200be1cf41cd03869a46fe7226e7450af7a6545bfc474c9/idna-2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58kB)
remote:        Collecting urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 (from requests->forex-python==1.5->-r /tmp/build_460e46d9ff4616a54e3ebd7caa495280/requirements.txt (line 5))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e8/74/6e4f91745020f967d09332bb2b8b9b10090957334692eb88ea4afe91b77f/urllib3-1.25.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (125kB)
remote:        Collecting six>=1.5 (from python-dateutil>=2.6.1->pandas==0.25.3->-r /tmp/build_460e46d9ff4616a54e3ebd7caa495280/requirements.txt (line 11))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/65/eb/1f97cb97bfc2390a276969c6fae16075da282f5058082d4cb10c6c5c1dba/six-1.14.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 (from matplotlib!=3.0.0,>=2.0.0->scikit-image==0.16.2->-r /tmp/build_460e46d9ff4616a54e3ebd7caa495280/requirements.txt (line 16))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5d/bc/1e58593167fade7b544bfe9502a26dc860940a79ab306e651e7f13be68c2/pyparsing-2.4.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (67kB)
remote:        Collecting cycler>=0.10 (from matplotlib!=3.0.0,>=2.0.0->scikit-image==0.16.2->-r /tmp/build_460e46d9ff4616a54e3ebd7caa495280/requirements.txt (line 16))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f7/d2/e07d3ebb2bd7af696440ce7e754c59dd546ffe1bbe732c8ab68b9c834e61/cycler-0.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting kiwisolver>=1.0.1 (from matplotlib!=3.0.0,>=2.0.0->scikit-image==0.16.2->-r /tmp/build_460e46d9ff4616a54e3ebd7caa495280/requirements.txt (line 16))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f8/a1/5742b56282449b1c0968197f63eae486eca2c35dcd334bab75ad524e0de1/kiwisolver-1.1.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (90kB)
remote:        Collecting decorator>=4.3.0 (from networkx>=2.0->scikit-image==0.16.2->-r /tmp/build_460e46d9ff4616a54e3ebd7caa495280/requirements.txt (line 16))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8f/b7/f329cfdc75f3d28d12c65980e4469e2fa373f1953f5df6e370e84ea2e875/decorator-4.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Installing collected packages: soupsieve, beautifulsoup4, bs4, pytz, Django, dj-database-url, whitenoise, psycopg2, django-heroku, django-widget-tweaks, certifi, chardet, idna, urllib3, requests, simplejson, forex-python, gunicorn, numpy, Pillow, imageio, img2pdf, imutils, opencv-python-headless, six, python-dateutil, pandas, Pygments, pypandoc, PyPDF2, pyparsing, cycler, kiwisolver, matplotlib, decorator, networkx, PyWavelets, scipy, scikit-image, xlrd, more-itertools, zipp, lxml, python-docx, pymupdf
remote:          Running setup.py install for bs4: started
remote:            Running setup.py install for bs4: finished with status 'done'
remote:          Running setup.py install for psycopg2: started
remote:            Running setup.py install for psycopg2: finished with status 'done'
remote:          Running setup.py install for simplejson: started
remote:            Running setup.py install for simplejson: finished with status 'done'
remote:          Running setup.py install for forex-python: started
remote:            Running setup.py install for forex-python: finished with status 'done'
remote:          Running setup.py install for img2pdf: started
remote:            Running setup.py install for img2pdf: finished with status 'done'
remote:          Running setup.py install for imutils: started
remote:            Running setup.py install for imutils: finished with status 'done'
remote:          Running setup.py install for pypandoc: started
remote:            Running setup.py install for pypandoc: finished with status 'done'
remote:          Running setup.py install for PyPDF2: started
remote:            Running setup.py install for PyPDF2: finished with status 'done'
remote:          Running setup.py install for python-docx: started
remote:            Running setup.py install for python-docx: finished with status 'done'
remote:          Running setup.py install for pymupdf: started
remote:            Running setup.py install for pymupdf: finished with status 'error'
remote:            Complete output from command /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-205xyxft/pymupdf/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-a457z02t-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
remote:            running install
remote:            running build
remote:            running build_py
remote:            creating build
remote:            creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
remote:            creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/fitz
remote:            copying fitz/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/fitz
remote:            copying fitz/fitz.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/fitz
remote:            copying fitz/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/fitz
remote:            copying fitz/__main__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/fitz
remote:            running build_ext
remote:            building 'fitz._fitz' extension
remote:            creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
remote:            creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/fitz
remote:            gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/usr/include/mupdf -I/usr/local/include/mupdf -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python3.6m -c fitz/fitz_wrap.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/fitz/fitz_wrap.o
remote:            fitz/fitz_wrap.c:2732:10: fatal error: fitz.h: No such file or directory
remote:             #include <fitz.h>
remote:                      ^~~~~~~~
remote:            compilation terminated.
remote:            error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
remote:
remote:            ----------------------------------------
remote:        Command "/app/.heroku/python/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-205xyxft/pymupdf/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-a457z02t-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-205xyxft/pymupdf/
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to compare-tool.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/compare-tool.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/compare-tool.git'
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Some debugging , I have solved the Issue .

The issue was with the new version of PyMuPDF and therefore , instead of using the latest version of PyMuPdf , I used the old version.

In the Aptfile , Instead of adding Mupdf-tools , add

```
http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/m/mupdf/mupdf_1.14.0+ds1-4_amd64.deb
```

In *requirements.txt* , instead of adding PyMuPDF , add

```
PyMuPDF==1.14.20
```

This Should Solve it.

Answer (score 3):

I experienced exactly the same issue as you have described.

Prior to this, my Django Heroku app was working just fine with no issue using PyMuPDF / Fitz. So I was left to conclude that this build failure was a totally new problem resulting in some change.

In my case, I had just recently updated my dependencies which included PyMuPDF.

What solved my problem was to lock PyMuPDF at version 1.16.0.

pymupdf = "==1.16.0"

I think the latest version as of time of writing is either 1.16.1 or 1.16.2.

I am not 100% sure about the root cause but I suspect that it's because the latest version of PyMuPDF may not allow for backwards compatibility with older versions of pip.

Upon checking the pip version running on my live Heroku dyno, I get:

"You are using pip version 9.0.2, however version 20.0.2 is available."

If you are using the default Heroku Python environment, the same might apply to you.

Let us know if freezing your PyMuPDF version solves the issue for you as well!

Comment: Thank you for your response , I had already figured out that this was the issue but your input helped regardless.